# Change image according to step automatically

Tags: jquery

I have some steps.like

```
<li>Step1</li>
<li>Step2</li>
<li>Step3</li>
<li>Step4</li>
<li>Step5</li>
```

And on each step i want to show their related image. Like i have another div

```
<div><img src="step1"></div>
```

I want that the step will highlight one by one and my image will change automatically according to that. Any Idea. Thanks in advance.

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $divs = $("div").show(),
        current = 0;

    $divs.eq(0).attr("style","color:red");

    function showNext() {
        if (current < $divs.length - 1) {
            $divs.eq(current).delay(2000).show('fast', function() {

                current++;
                $divs.eq(current).attr("style","color:red");
                showNext();
            });
        }
    }
    showNext();

});
```

Comment: you should come up with at least a minimum try.

Comment: tell us what you have done so far ..... SO is for helping people who have tried something and got stuck in the middle ..... Its not for asking Members to code for you ... Please do tell us what you have tried so far and we would willingly help you out and tell where you went wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('li[id^="step"]').click(function(){
    var imagepath = jQuery(this).attr('dir');
    jQuery('#ImageDiv').find('img').attr('src',imagepath);
});
});
</script>
<style>
li{ cusrsor:pointer; padding:10px; }
</style>

<li id="step1" dir="images1.jpg">Step1</li>
<li id="step2" dir="images2.jpg">Step2</li>
<li id="step3" dir="images3.jpg">Step3</li>
<li id="step4" dir="images4.jpg">Step4</li>
<li id="step5" dir="images5.jpg">Step5</li>

<div id="ImageDiv"><img src="images1.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works on click. I want to set timer to work itself like slider like step 1 to 5 after 5 again start mover from step 1 and on hover it will stop moving.

Comment: You have to set a variable and then you have to increment that variable on interval and if it reaches to last value you have to reset that variable that's how you can loop.